# Stack Exchange and CALEA

Tags: discussion, legal

The CALEA extension is [described by CNET News](http://m.cnet.com/news/57428067) in a sort of frightening report.  Specifically, this:

> "If you create a service, product, or app that allows a user to communicate, you get the privilege of adding that extra coding," an industry representative who has reviewed the FBI's draft legislation told CNET.
>
> The FBI general counsel's office has drafted a proposed law that the bureau claims is the best solution: requiring that social-networking Web sites and providers of VoIP, instant messaging, and Web e-mail alter their code to ensure their products are wiretap-friendly

As this legislation has slipped by quite quietly, I wonder how it might affect the SE sites with regards to the sharing of personal information about its users (especially considering varying age groups).  Obviously, if this is classified or something, then by all means, close this question, but I am just curious.

Comment: My apologies for the mobile CNET link, they have a lovely trap on their mobile site which redirects all mobile traffic to the mobile page despite clicking the "Desktop version" button.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't relevant as long as SE isn't providing internet service without CALEA hardware...

Comment: Nothing here really explains what the heck CALEA is, and I don't feel like going to Google. It's night time, I'm tired, meh.

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_Assistance_for_Law_Enforcement_Act), CALEA applies to manufacturers of telecommunications equipment and carriers:

> CALEA's purpose is to enhance the ability of law enforcement and intelligence agencies to conduct electronic surveillance by requiring that telecommunications carriers and manufacturers of telecommunications equipment modify and design their equipment, facilities, and services to ensure that they have built-in surveillance capabilities, allowing federal agencies to monitor all telephone, broadband internet, and VoIP traffic in real-time.

Last I heard, the closest thing SE has to a telecommunications equipment manufacturing division was still in the [commitment phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing).

Comment: Nice try, but I ain't falling for it! http://www.majhost.com/gallery/bobobo1/bzpowertshirtproject/flimzy-thought.png

Comment: It's a CALEA _extension_, of course wikipedia is out of date: "The FBI general counsel's office has drafted a proposed law that the bureau claims is the best solution: requiring that social-networking Web sites and providers of VoIP, instant messaging, and Web e-mail alter their code to ensure their products are wiretap-friendly."

Comment: Ah, fortunately Stack Exchange does not offer any of those services, @CodaFi